# Ionic 4 - InAppBrowser with target "_blank" doesn't work on IOS?

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4, inappbrowser

I'm new to ionic developement, and have been facing some problem with InAppBrowser.

My app is suposed to be a WebView, running on InAppBrowser, the target that i'm providing is "_blank" because i need the events to detect when a pdf url gonna be open, so i can open that url with browserTabs, it's works fine on android.

But i can't make it work on IOS, when i set the target as "_blank", i get a white screen, it's only works with target as "_self" but from what i could see the events doesn't work with "_self".

I've tried add in these tags on my config.xml:

```
<allow-intent href="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<access origin="*" />
```

I've tried add in the CSP on my index.html

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

None of theses tags worked.

So, if anyone has a light of what i could do, i would be very thankfull.

Edit 1: Codes:

```
browserOptions: string = "location=no,beforeload=yes,toolbar=no";

openInAppBrowser(urlToOpen: string) {

      this.browser = this._inAppBrowser.create(urlToOpen, '_blank',this.browserOptions );

      this.browser.on("beforeload").subscribe( event => {
        if(event.url.match("/report") || event.url.indexOf("/relatorio")>0) {
          this._browserTab.isAvailable()
              .then(isAvailable => {
                if (isAvailable) {
                  this._browserTab.openUrl(event.url);
                }
              });
          } 
        });
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the code that is calling and setting the options for the InAppBrowser?

Comment: @NickyTheWrench Added

Comment: Is there any reason why you are using `.create()` instead of `.open()`?